# Warning C4121 behavior & structure alignment (Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, memory-alignment

Let’s consider below declaration.
(Visual Studio 2010, Warning level 4)

```
#pragma pack(push, 2)
#define PADDING 1 // --- <case 1>
/*
#define PADDING 2 // --- <case 2>
*/
struct foo
{
    char a[PADDING];
    int b;
};
```

#### Symptom

If you set PADDING as `<case 1>`, it will definitely produce C4121. But for `<case 2>`, it can be compiled without any warning. The two cases have same structure layout, offset of "b" is 2 bytes.
I expected C4121 for `<case 2>`, because "b" is not aligned on the multiple of `sizeof(int)` boundary. (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kabt0ka3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). I couldn’t find 2010 version.)

#### Question

I wonder whether it is reasonable that only `<case 1>` produce C4121, as the resulting structure layouts (alignment) are the same.
Am I missing anything important? Should I ignore C4121?

#### PS

Actually, I had been faced with this situation with

> - default alignment value (8 bytes)
> - pointer to member function of undefined (forward declaration only) class (16 bytes).

So, I think specific alignment value is not the point. I’ve written above sample code to make things simple.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kabt0ka3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: adding to the comment above, if you take a look at the link you'll see that your ability to ignore is a function of your sensitivity to performance and to the machine's ability to generate unaligned accesses. On some machines, that'll result in an exception

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I read MSDN document before posting my question. But the link could not explain this symptom, I think.

My question is close to "why does not C4121 occur even if data is not aligned on boundaries that are multiples of the data's size?"

Comment: You ought to post this to connect.microsoft.com, it certainly doesn't match the description of the warning.  It *could* match the spirit of the warning, you'd normally only use such unusual packing when you try to get rid of the padding bytes between the members.  That's a bit of a stretch, connect ought to give you something better than a guess.

Comment: @Hans Passant. Thank you for your suggestion. I will visit microsoft.
By the way, I think it could happen even usual packing as stated on "PS".

Answer (score 1):

If you ignore this warnig you have to keep in mind that :

> When data is not aligned on boundaries that are multiples of the data's size performance can degrade and if you port your code to a RISC machine it will not compile.

At least, you have to decide if you can take the risk to have an exception thrown...

Using `#pragma pack()` to solved it is a good way but there is an issue with that :

> The #pragma pack directive can only be used to reduce the packing size of a structure from the project default packing. This leads to interoperability problems with library headers which use for example #pragma pack(8) if you set a project packing to smaller than this. The MSDN documentation[5] states that if the #pragma pack packing is larger than or equal to the project packing, it will be ignored.
>
> **For this reason, one should never set a project packing to any value other than the default of 8 bytes, as it would break the #pragma pack directives used in library headers and result in binary incompatibilities between structures.**

But also :

> the x86 architecture originally did not require aligned memory access and still works without it.

I will suggest you to avoid this warning, it will be safer...

On way to solve this is to reverse the order of the `struct` members as suggested here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kabt0ka3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

**EDIT :**
One more additional link who explains what is **data structure alignement** and the problems coming with : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment (I suggest you to read the *definitions* and *problems* sections)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you tell me the source where "if the #pragma pack packing is larger than or equal to the project packing, it will be ignored." is described? I couldn't find the document.

Anyway, "C4121 strange(?) behavior" seems to be caused by compiler issue.

Comment: I've found a resource, probably you mentioned about ignoring pragma pack. [Working with Packing Structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253935(v=vs.80).aspx).
It's under the category `[RISC, Visual Studio 2005]`, so I'm not sure if it's a general or specific for RISC and VS2005.

Comment: If I remember it was on the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) on the section : *Default packing and #pragma pack*. But I also read it on a C++ book (I don't remember with one, it was some years ago :) )

Comment: @hun Did you solve your problem ? Or at least did you find the answer to your question ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be a compiler issue:

```
#pragma pack(push, 2)
struct foo
{
    char a[3];
    int b;
}; 

int main()
{
    foo f[2];
    cout << "sizeof(f) = " << sizeof(f) << endl;
    cout << "&f[0] =" << &f[0] << endl;
    cout << "&f[1] =" << &f[1] << endl;
    cout << "&f[0].b =" << &(f[0].b) << endl;
    cout << "&f[1].b =" << &(f[1].b) << endl;
}
```

With 1 and 3 I get the warning, with 2 not, although with 1 and 2 the addresses are the same.

Comment: Thank you for your test. My experiment showed same result as yours. My "guess" was that C4121 was not produced if "b" was already aligned on multiples of alignment value without padding. (2, 4, 6... for this case)

Comment: yes, but as I am compiling for x64 I would expect pack(push, 2) generating the warning, as the int of the struct will not be aligned on a 4 byte boundary.